# I want to read the start_address from the google map in xml format in php

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, xml-parsing

I want to parse the `start_address` node from `Google Map` ([Map Example Url](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=london&destination=heathrow&sensor=false)) using `PHP`, I've tried in `JSON` format which works, but my existing system has the `xml` so I need to parse in `xml`. How Can I parse `xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
$mapUrl = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=london&destination=heathrow&sensor=false';
$xml_obj = simplexml_load_file($mapUrl);
echo $xml_obj->route->leg->start_address[0]; // String Output: "London, UK"
```

Check [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php).